# When to break lines?

Tags: formatting, best-practices, sourcecode

I am very new to LaTeX.

A newline in the input file does not mean anything to LaTeX. An empty line in the input file means a new paragraph.

Trouble is, when I view my sources with different text editors on different displays, they look very different (and always bad). So I find myself chopping lines to the about 80-th character or so.

This brings the MS Word problem - introduce a line, or even a single word, and you need to edit the whole following paragraph in order that it is nicely 
positioned on the display (talking about the .tex file).

Using `--soft-wrap` wraps lines around, but is not pleasing to the eye, plus a single move of the cursor could scroll a whole screen - hardly intuative.

*How do I write .tex source file, so that anyone - using an IDE or just any editor, can view and edit them comfortable?*

Comment: basically you shouldn't worry about it. I usually set my editor to insert a (hard) newline somewhere around column 75 but if I edit text and the lines get longer or shorter it doesn't matter (although fill-paragraphs command would re-wrap the file if I wanted to tidy it up before sending to someone.

Comment: not a definitive answer, but [on this web page](http://tug.org/tugboat/location.html) are the recommendations we give to tugboat authors to make our life as editors as painless as possible.  (note that some of these recommendations are very tugboat-centric, and not necessarily applicable to other publications.)

Comment: When they deserve it!! Bwaha

Comment: See [What are coding conventions in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95687) and [Styleguide for LaTeX similar to the Google styleguides?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12171)

Answer (score 5):

[Third way](http://xkcd.com/1285/) is my personal preference. It is helpful for diffs and if you use a repository to keep track of your code. Then let your editor soft wrap long sentences.

Comment: This sounds like a very logical and clean solution. I'll try it out!

Comment: +1 One sentence, one line! This is semantically correct and can be valuable if you put your source code under versioning control!

Answer (score 4):

I use an editor with word wrap on. If you're using Windows, Notepad++ is great. In Linux there are many great editors, but even gedit automatically wraps lines. If you're using Eclipse, its soft-wrap feature is kinda buggy and I never really found it very well suited to Latex editing, but it's still better than hard-wrapping, because as you said, you have to redo it any time you change to a different screen size (and doing so wreaks havoc on the diff of any version control you might be using), which is tedious.

TLDR: best practice in this is, imho, to let your text editor soft-wrap the lines for you.

Comment: I am tempted to accept your answer as least evil alternative. Two problems remain. 1) on a non-configured editor, lines will be very ugly. 2) Navigating with the arrow keys becomes significantly more difficult - pressing `down` can scroll 10 lines or only 1. Moving to the middle of the paragraph is far worse - here the `End` key is no rescue to us.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like emacs+auxtex. It's got a keyboard shortcut for formatting paragraphs, regions and sections, i.e., it does nice line breaks and indenting.