# How to keep the source code in order

Tags: sourcecode

My first documents were very simple - just few rows of preamble and then the document content with the default settings - but most of my current projects require much more setup and the source code becomes very messy and quite difficult to read and review. I'm wondering if exists a more or less official style guide for LaTeX sources, like [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python. If not, what general rules should I follow to have an ordered code?

I'm particularly interested in the following:

1. indentation
2. new lines in commands with several arguments or long options lists, such as
   packages setup in the preamble
3. structure of the preamble
4. use of new lines to enhance readability (not the empty ones for new paragraphs, of course)
5. use of \input{}

Comment: [Styleguide for LaTeX similar to the Google styleguides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12171/134144) and [Are there any coding style guidelines for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40775/134144) and [Automatic style guide for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288382/134144)  might be related

Comment: Also possibly relevant, esp. for item #3, "Structure of the preamble": [Best practice on organising your preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40760/5001).

Comment: As for \input, the question is whether seeing the contents is useful or just confusing or overwhelming.

Comment: The guideline is make the code as clean as possible *for your taste*. Many people want indentation but for me is more difficult read the code in this way. You may want `\begin{foo} bah \end{foo}` in three lines with "bah" indented,  but  I want this in a single line except if "bah" is too long. I prefer \par instead of blank line except for plain text, etc.

Comment: For indentation, perhaps latexindent